# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams - how to log incomming messages in stream?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to log inbound messages from stream function?
Is there some kind of interceptor that allows me to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Log incoming string using `KStream.peek(StreamLogger::in)` methods :)