# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Stream - How to handle runtime exceptions?

Tags: exception, stream, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm struggling with customization of my spring kafka streams application.
I have been trying to configure handling uncaught (runtime exceptions) at my KStreams.

Refering to documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder - it should be done like that:

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class CustomKafkaStreamsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer() {
        return factoryBean -> {
            factoryBean.setKafkaStreamsCustomizer(new KafkaStreamsCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(KafkaStreams kafkaStreams) {
                    kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
                        log.error("An exception has occurred={}", e.getMessage()) ;
                    });

                }
            });
        };
    }

}
```

Later on I have a KStream

```java
    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, Transaction>,
            KStream<String, Transaction>> paymentExecution() {
        return stream -> stream
                .peek((k, v) -> {
                    if (v.getStatus().equals(PaymentStatus.UNKNOWN)) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException();
                    }
                });
    }
```

If I send Transaction with UNKNOWN status StreamThread dies due to IllegalStateException and then my KStream is not consuming anymore any incomming requests.

```java
Exception in thread "payment-d4b6ddd2-40ab-4eeb-afe4-e7fc3caa2b9c-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=payment-request, partition=0, offset=13, stacktrace=java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at payment.process.PaymentExecutionRequestProcessor.lambda$paymentExecution$4(PaymentExecutionRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:96)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1033)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:690)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:696)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1033)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:690)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at payment.process.PaymentExecutionRequestProcessor.lambda$paymentExecution$4(PaymentExecutionOrchestratorProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:96)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:679)
```

Is there something that I miss? Or maybe there is more appropriate to handle runtime exceptions that rise while processing stream?

After runtime exception I want commit that exception-event, and then I want my StreamThread-1 to be able to still consume events.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can modify your setUncaughtExceptionHandler to be something like this

```
(throwable -> {
 log.error("An exception has occurred={}", e.getMessage()) ;
 return StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD; });
```

Essentially, the REPLACE_THREAD should close out the current thread and NOT kill the app/stream and continue on with the stream. Please see this post for more detail
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68058414/1799107

Answer (score 0):

If the application reaches the `UncaughtExcpetionHandler`, then the stream thread is already stopped and too late to recover. It won't continue processing. It is provided for you to take any graceful shutdown measures before exiting the application. You need to restart the application in order to continue the processing. You can probably look into using something like the branching feature in Kafka Streams to ignore the records with unknown status, something like below (I haven't tested this, but should work).  The idea is to create a branch for the incoming `KStream` to filter out any records with this `UNKNOWN` status to be ignored rather than throwing an exception. It is still possible to log the unknown ones and provide any additional logic etc.

```
@Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, Transaction>,
            KStream<String, Transaction>[]> paymentExecution() {
        return stream -> stream
                .branch( (k, v) - !v.getStatus().equals(PaymentStatus.UNKNOWN));
    }
```

Comment: So, there is no any elegant way to recover from exception? I mean runtime exceptions can occur by developer mistakes or whatever. Example with IllegalStateException was feigned, just to test he behavior of `UncaughtExcpetionHandler` which as you explained doesn't work in that way.

So there is no any nice way to recover from these cases, the only way is to restart an application? Well... that sound like some kind of edge case :(

Comment: Also, could you refer in some free time to my other question regarding logging incomming data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683790/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streams-how-to-log-incomming-messages-in-stream

Answer (score 0):

You can send the failures to a DLQ or configure a RetryTemplate to handle the exceptions as shown in https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_error_handling